Solution Explanation for 2016 AMC 10A Problem 20
This is a combinatorics problem from the 2016 AMC 10A [ Problem 20 ]

For some particular value of $N$, when $(a+b+c+d+1)^N$ is expanded and
like terms are combined, the resulting expression contains exactly
$1001$ terms that include all four variables $a, b,c,$ and $d$, each
to some positive power. What is $N$?

https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/2016_AMC_10A_Problems/Problem_20



Given above is one of the solutions found on AoPS.I am familiar with the expression for the number of terms in a multinomial of k terms and power n is $ n + k - 1 \choose n$ from Stars and Bars. I was also able to see that, since $a, b, c, d$ are raised to positive powers $ n_1, n_2, n_3, n_4$ and 1 is raised a nonnegative power $n_5$, that by letting $$ n_1' = n_1 + 1$$$$ n_2' = n_2 + 1$$$$ n_3' = n_3 + 1$$ $$ n_4' = n_4 + 1$$. Then $$ n_1' + n_2' + n_3' + n_4' + n_5 = N -4 $$ Giving $ (N - 4)+4 \choose 4$$=$$N \choose 4$ terms by Stars and Bars.
What I fail completely to understand is from where the provided answer derives $ N \choose 4$. I understand the use of Hockeystick but what would $N-1 \choose 3$, $N-2 \choose 3$, up till $3 \choose 3$ actually correspond to. Also in a different answer I saw


Link to second answer: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c5h1193470p23100231

being used. I dont understand why that identity holds, or what it signifies in the problem. I think this second derived identity (from wherever it popped up; it seems unmotivated to me) is wrong. Could anyone explain both those solutions in a way that is motivated to be something you would do by relating it to the problem

It seems to me that they are conditioning on how many powers of $1$ you have. $\quad$ (Which is a horrendous step to make, because they could have just done it directly, which was what you did in the writeup. $\quad$ Edit: Ah, that's what they did in Solution 1, and this is Solution 2, so not that horrendous)

Oh, right, you could interpret the first one in that way. What about the second one

You should link to the different answer. It's very likely a typo on the authors part (but we can't tell their intentions given your screenshot).

I have attached a link to the post, however, just by trial, i think the identity is false. Clearly for N = 4, it doesnt hold

For 2, looking at the writeup, I'd say that the author made a mistake with not accounting for $ \alpha _ i > 0$ (and presented no awareness that we needed to do so), and they are just counting the number of possible terms. Then, they make a mistake with this summation, which "corrects" it. As such, I would have graded this solution a $0^+$. (I'm not a mindreader. I could guess their intentions, but that's just a guess.)

If you expand expression as $((a+b+c+d) + (1))^n$ as a binomial, we we would get terms such as $(a+b+c+d)^n, (a+b+c+d)^{n-1}, \cdots$. The number of ways from first term is $\binom{n-1}{3}$, from second term is $\binom{n-2}{3}$ and so on. That will give the hockey stick. And since this way and non expanding are equal this will also serve as proof of the hockey stick identity.
